# I was scraping this website last week, and now i no longer can and can't figure out why

Tags: python, web-scraping

I had to get a new computer this past week. Ever since I've gotten the new computer I have not been able to scrape pages I could several times a day just last week. This makes me think the new version of python is the problem or my code is poorly written (I had to re-write it from memory and am fairly new to python). Any Advice?

I'm getting a 403 Error, but am shocked I'm getting that error since I was scraping this page last week.

I've tried the code below:

```
URL = "https://sports.il.betmgm.com/cds-api/bettingoffer/fixture-view?x-bwin-accessid=ZTg4YWEwMTgtZTlhYy00MWRkLWIzYWYtZjMzODI5ZDE0Mjc5&lang=en-us&country=US&userCountry=US&subdivision=US-Illinois&offerMapping=All&scoreboardMode=Full&fixtureIds=14351210&state=Latest&includePrecreatedBetBuilder=true&supportVirtual=false&useRegionalisedConfiguration=true"

html_text = requests.get(URL)
print(html_text)
```

Comment: You need to provide more description e.g. what error messages were you getting?

Comment: Too little information. With the code you are showing, nothing seems to be strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to get correct Json data by specifying the `User-Agent` HTTP header:

```py
import requests

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/115.0"
}

url = "https://sports.il.betmgm.com/cds-api/bettingoffer/fixture-view?x-bwin-accessid=ZTg4YWEwMTgtZTlhYy00MWRkLWIzYWYtZjMzODI5ZDE0Mjc5&lang=en-us&country=US&userCountry=US&subdivision=US-Illinois&offerMapping=All&scoreboardMode=Full&fixtureIds=14351210&state=Latest&includePrecreatedBetBuilder=true&supportVirtual=false&useRegionalisedConfiguration=true"

data = requests.get(url, headers=headers).json()
print(data)
```

Prints:

```py
{'fixture': {'optionMarkets': [], 'games': [{'id': 942688385, 'name': {'value': 'How many passing yards will Justin Fields (Chi) record in the regular season?', 'sign': 'YvdaPw=='}, 'results': [{'id': -1533493332, 'odds': 1.91, 'name': {'value': 'Over 2899.5', 'sign': 'tNKigQ=='}, 'visibility': 'Visible', 'numerator': 10, 'denominator': 11, 'americanOdds': -110}, {'id': -1533493331, 'odds': 1.91, 'name': {'value': 'Under 2899.5', 'sign': 'hGoWVw=='}, 'visibility': 'Visible', 'numerator': 10, 'denominator': 11, 'americanOdds': -110}], 'templateId': 37615, 'categoryId': 1528, 'resultOrder': 'Default', 'combo1': 'NoLeagueCombo', 'combo2': 'Single', 'visibility': 'Visible', 'category': 'Specials',

...
```

Comment: Thank you, i noticed when i take away the .json() I get a "Response [200]". What does that mean?

Comment: @Gio_Bart That means you got Response with the [HTTP code 200](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/200) from the server.

Comment: When you receive a "Response [200]" status code, it typically means that your request was successful, and the data you requested is available in the response object returned by the requests library.